# How to do OCR with a Savin 9228 printer?

Tags: network-printer, ocr

At work we have a Savin 9228 printer that I read on the website can do OCR.  But I looked in the manual and I can't find any mention of OCR.  Does the printer actually do OCR or does the printer scan and some other software on my PC do it on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you use scanners/[MFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multifunction_device)s to scan and OCR software then converts to editable text. In some cases though I've seen that OCR capabilities might be included as part of the driver software itself, which might be the case here.

As per the [Knowledge Base](https://savin.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92694), looks like you might need to use the device's Operation Panel to navigate to `Scanner / Scan Settings / Scan Type` and specify the type of scan you want:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Apparently you can save directly as PDF:

[image: 4]

---

If that does not help to create editable PDFs, see if you have [DeskTopBinder](https://savin.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/80738) software installed that can help you perform OCR on scanned images:

[image: 5]

Newer models might have [Personal Paperless Document Manager](http://www.ricoh-usa.com/services_and_solutions/services_solutions_details.aspx?cid=74&scid=57&sid=1536), OmniPage or similar software bundled that you can use to do the same thing:

[image: 6]